# Overriding css of a dropdown without affecting some

Tags: html, css, dropdown

The title seems off because I can't explain it well, but here it goes.

I'm trying to make a dropdown with each item in a horizontal form and without affecting the other dropdown in the same component.

I implement all of the dropdown like this and I had to apply this to make it horizontal:

```css
.dropdown-menu {
    margin-right:-1000px;
}

.dropdown-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is that, when I apply this. the other dropdowns would be affected too.

My question is that, how do I make it so that only specific dropdown would be a affected by the horizontal `css`?

Comment: Can you modify the HTML? If so, you could just add a class and apply the style to that.

Comment: There are numerous ways to target specific items even if they have same structure and classes. You need to be more specific in CSS targeting using some of the selectors : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp , and no one can help you without seeing the rest of the elements in question, so make [mre] in order for someone to help you.